# Getting error inside Try block WebDriverWait - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

I'm trying a Try/Exception block that uses Selenium to make click in a web button. But even if I use a Try/Exception block, the code breaks inside the Try block.
Part of the code is the following:

```
...
###### click left bar option
select_element(driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id='mnu_Matrícula']")

###### click suboption
select_element(driver, By.XPATH, "//*[@id='2020']")
time.sleep(20)
            
try:
    # click new creation
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-panel/div/div[2]/div/button"))).click()
    # select_element(driver, By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-panel/div/div[2]/div/button")
    time.sleep(10)
except:
    status = "ERROR"

...
```

The error I'm getting mentions:

```
Cell In[23], line 121
   119 try:
   120     # click new creation
--> 121     WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-panel/div/div[2]/div/button"))).click()
   122     #select_element(driver, By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-panel/div/div[2]/div/button")

   raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I also have to mention that I iterate this code many times, and this error happens once each N times, but I don't get why.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: need to see what exception error you are getting, if you change except to `except Exception as e: print(e)`, pls share what it prints.

Comment: @simpleApp The point is that the error does occur inside Try block. It breaks the code and does not go into Except block, so nothing will be printed

Comment: how is it possible that it doesn't go to the except block?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to specify which Exception needs to occur for the except block to be utilized, as in:

```py
try:
    # click new creation
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-panel/div/div[2]/div/button"))).click()
    # select_element(driver, By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-panel/div/div[2]/div/button")
    time.sleep(10)
except TimeoutException:
    status = "ERROR"
```

Don't forget to import the Exception as well.